# Remove head script not working in custom component

Tags: component, php, javascript, header

I'm using this lines to remove header scripts of Joomla I don't need it :

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$dontInclude = array(
    '/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js'
);

foreach($doc->_scripts as $key => $script){
    if(in_array($key, $dontInclude)){
        unset($doc->_scripts[$key]);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine in all pages except those who point to a custom component. There is no override of head in my component and cache is disabled.

I'm using Joomla 3.3.3

**Edit:**
If I print the document object from my component, scripts is an empty array...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do realise that unsetting this file will result in a console log error and loss of functionality such as editing an article in the frontend

Comment: Could you use a plugin such as JQuery easy to exclude the script from specific pages? Plugin details here http://www.simplifyyourweb.com/index.php/developers-corner/90-solving-jquery-jquery-and-jquery-mootools-conflict-issues-with-the-jquery-easy-plugin

Comment: @Lodder I know, I just want to replace the current version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Where are you putting this code? In a component, a plugin, your template?

Comment: Be sure to use the **underscore**. It's `_scripts` and not `scripts`.

Comment: Are you working with raw view instead of html view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be doing this in a system plugin using the onBeforeRender event.  At this point in execution, the page is about to be rendered, so the scripts should be in place.

Something like this:

```
function onBeforeRender() {
  $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

  $dontInclude = array(
    '/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js'
  );

  foreach($doc->_scripts as $key => $script){
    if(in_array($key, $dontInclude)){
        unset($doc->_scripts[$key]);
    }
  } 
}
```